# Getting DbUpdateException when adding a row

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, code-first

I'm trying to add a record in a table, but it's not working. The error message tells me that I cannot insert an explicit value in identity column for `ProductCategories`, but I don't know that I'm doing that. Maybe there is something I'm not getting about entity navigation, or my models are somehow not correctly linked?

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ProductCategories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>   Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Products' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__108_0(Task result)
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch+d__32.MoveNext()

This is the code that fails (at `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> FrontPageProduct(ViewModelFrontPageProduct frontPageProduct)
{
    var fpp = new FrontPageProduct()
    {
        ProductCategoryId = frontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId,
        ProductId = frontPageProduct.ProductId,
        SortOrder = 0
    };
    _context.Add(fpp);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return View("Index", new { id = fpp.ProductCategoryId, tab = 2 });
}
```

These are the involved entity models:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<FrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }
    public List<ProductInCategory> InCategories { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentCategory))]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();
    public List<ProductInCategory> ProductInCategory { get; set; }
}

public class FrontPageProduct
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductCategoryId")]
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

The debug inspection of the `fpp`-object shows that the values for `ProductCategoryId` and `ProductId` are correct:

[image: Debug-info]

Where is/are my mistake/s?

**EDIT** I added the suggested `[Key]` and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to all the models, but I still get the same error.

I think that the `Id` field is always set to be primary key as default in EF anyway.

**EDIT 2** I tried adding `[FromBody]` in my controller method, but that only resulted in a blank screen, no error message, and no changes being made to the database.

**EDIT 3** I added `[ForeignKey("ProductId")]` and `[ForeignKey("ProductCategoryId")]` to the `FrontPageProduct` model, but still get the same SqlException.

**EDIT 4** These are the foreign keys of my four tables:

`FrontPageProducts`:

FK_FrontPageProducts_ProductCategories_ProductCategoryId

FK_FrontPageProducts_Products_ProductId

`ProductCategories`:

FK_ProductCategories_ProductCategories_ParentId

`Products`:

none

`ProductsInCategories`:

FK_ProductsInCategories_FrontPageProducts_FrontPageProductId

FK_ProductsInCategories_ProductCategories_ProductCategoryId

FK_ProductsInCategories_Products_ProductId

Comment: try adding navigation properties to FrontPageProduct

Comment: The error suggests the `ProductCategory` doesn't exist and it's trying to create it but it can't set `FrontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId` because you've explicitly set it.  Are you sure your model binding is working correctly?  I notice you're not using `[FromBody]`.

Comment: @Brad I tried `[FromBody]`, but that didn't do anything good for me. Please see edit 2 at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I just realized you also have properties for collections like public List<FrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }, please mark them with InversePropertyAttribute.

Comment: @hazimdikenli Adding `[InverseProperty("FrontPageProduct")]` to the `ProductCategory` property `FrontPageProduct` and the `Product` property `InFrontPages` gives me this error message when I try to add migration: The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'InFrontPages' on type 'Product' is not valid. The property 'FrontPageProduct' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'FrontPageProduct'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property.

Comment: @Stian in the InverseProperty you should specify the PropertyName not the class name. So it should be [InverseProperty("ProductCategory")]

Comment: @hazimdikenli I added `[InverseProperty("Product")]` to `InFrontPages` in `Product` and `[InverseProperty("ProductCategory")]` to `FrontPageProduct` in `ProductCategory`, but I still get SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FrontPageProducts_Products_ProductId". The conflict occurred in database "MyStore", table "dbo.Products", column 'Id'.

Comment: I think your model might have generated some correlation tables like FrontPageProducts_Products, can you check your database if that is the case?

Comment: @hazimdikenli No, but now I initialized a new database, and tried seeding it with new data. Then I discovered that the table `ProductsInCategories` had gotten a field with the name `FrontPageProductId`, which is not given by the model. When I tried inserting a value into that field, I got the same error message as described before.

Comment: @hazimdikenli I'm a bit embarresed to say this, but this whole problem was not in the database or controller action. I had a wrong variable name in a hidden field in the view. Now it's working! Thank you so much for your effort! I will accept your answer now. :D

Comment: @Stian I am happy to hear that it is resolved, I was also thinking that your db model was not aligned with your entity model, anyways, good luck, keep on coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't need to set DatabaseGenerated attribute for "int Id" fields, it is a convention and assumed that it is Identity Column.
Btw, are you sure you are getting the same error? The imgur link does not work for me. Do you really need Product and ProductCategory on your FrontPage class, if you can easily comment them out and test, please do so, if not you can try setting the values for them like below.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> FrontPageProduct(ViewModelFrontPageProduct frontPageProduct)
{
    var fpp = new FrontPageProduct()
    {
        ProductCategoryId = frontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId,
        ProductId = frontPageProduct.ProductId,
Product = _context.Set<Product>().Find(frontPageProduct.ProductId),
ProductCategory = _context.Set<ProductCategory>().Find(frontPageProduct.ProductCategoryId),
        SortOrder = 0
    };
    _context.Add(fpp);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return View("Index", new { id = fpp.ProductCategoryId, tab = 2 });
}
```

Apply Key and DatabaseGenerated attributes to every Id column on your models, so EF knows that it is an identity column and it needs to get back the generated id value.

```
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("Product")]
        public IEnumerable<FrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }
        public List<ProductInCategory> InCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductCategory
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentCategory))]
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();
        public List<ProductInCategory> ProductInCategory { get; set; }
    }

    public class FrontPageProduct
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductCategoryId ")]
        public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit: you should add navigation properties, just like I added above. Making them virtual also helps with lazy loading.

Comment: I still get the same error after making the changes. See edit 3 in my question.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions; Setting `Product` and `ProductCategory` by `.Find`ing them, and commenting out the nav.props. on the model. In both cases I get this exception: SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_FrontPageProducts_Products_ProductId". The conflict occurred in database "MyStore", table "dbo.Products", column 'Id'.

Comment: are you sure your foreign key relationships are correct? Are you sure you are getting the correct values for ProductId and ProductCategoryId from the client, please inspect them.

Comment: I have inspected the values for `ProductId` and `ProductCategoryId`, and they are correct. I have added another edit to my post, edit 4 - There you can see all the foreign keys: FK for `FrontPageProducts` are ProductCategories_ProductCategoryId and Products_ProductId. FK for `ProductCategories`: ProductCategories_ParentId. FK for `Products`: none. FK for `ProductsInCategories`: FrontPageProducts_FrontPageProductId, ProductCategories_ProductCategoryId and Products_ProductId.

Answer (score 1):

The Id field should be the primary key in the database so you can specify that in the entity models.  - Add the [Key]

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<FrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }
    public List<ProductInCategory> InCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you should also tell EF that ID column is autogenerated.
 [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Comment: @hazimdikenli I tried it, but it didn't make any difference. Still same error.